# Naming a dplyr count column

Tags: r, dplyr

According to https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tally.html, running the following code:

```
# Change the name of the newly created column:
species <-
 starwars %>%
 count(species, homeworld, sort = TRUE, name = "n_species_by_homeworld")
species
```

Should produce:

```
#> # A tibble: 58 x 3
#>    species homeworld n_species_by_homeworld
#>    <chr>   <chr>                      <int>
#>  1 Human   Tatooine                       8
#>  2 Human   <NA>                           5
#>  3 Human   Naboo                          5
#>  4 Gungan  Naboo                          3
#>  5 Human   Alderaan                       3
#>  6 <NA>    <NA>                           2
#>  7 <NA>    Naboo                          2
#>  8 Droid   <NA>                           2
#>  9 Droid   Tatooine                       2
#> 10 Human   Corellia                       2
#> # … with 48 more rows
```

However, I'm getting:

```
# A tibble: 58 x 4
   species  homeworld name                       n
   <chr>    <chr>     <chr>                  <int>
 1 Human    Tatooine  n_species_by_homeworld     8
 2 Human    Naboo     n_species_by_homeworld     5
 3 Human    NA        n_species_by_homeworld     5
 4 Gungan   Naboo     n_species_by_homeworld     3
 5 Human    Alderaan  n_species_by_homeworld     3
 6 Droid    Tatooine  n_species_by_homeworld     2
 7 Droid    NA        n_species_by_homeworld     2
 8 Human    Corellia  n_species_by_homeworld     2
 9 Human    Coruscant n_species_by_homeworld     2
10 Kaminoan Kamino    n_species_by_homeworld     2
# ... with 48 more rows
```

Help?

I'm running:

- R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
- Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
- Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Comment: your version of dplyr?

Comment: The documentation for dplyr you linked to is for `0.8.0` which isn't even on CRAN yet. If you want the bleeding edge features, you'll need to install from github. Otherwise just use `rename()` to rename the column

Comment: if you're unsure, `packageVersion("dplyr")`

Comment: Also if you use `reprex` (documentation at https://reprex.tidyverse.org/ it can help post your code and make it easier for others to help).

Comment: I see, yes I'm only running version 0.75 - so I'll install the very latest version from Github - thanks for the feedback